# PHP regex pattern for matching username

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I'm developing a laravel application where a user can refer to his profile by putting his username in the appropriate form.

Let's see an example:

A user named John can refer to his profile using the following text: @John

I spent several hours trying to understand how regex works, but this pattern is where i've got so far: `@([A-Za-z0-9]+)`

This pattern perfectly matches the example above, but it also matches other formats that it normally shouldn't.

I need some help creating the perfect pattern.

It should only match a string that starts with the @ symbol.
For example: @John, @Sam, @Bill, etc.

It shouldn't match a string that doesn't start with the @ symbol.
For example: a@John, something@Sam, 123@Bill, etc.

It should also match those formats that contain more than one @ symbols.
For example: @John@, @Sam@something, @Bill@@sometext, etc.
In this case the pattern should capture: John@, Sam@something, Bill@@sometext

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Which characters specifically are allowed to be captured in this "username"?

Comment: In these "appropriate form[s]" is the `@Username` allowed to be anywhere in a string, or only at the beginning?

Comment: A-Z, a-z, 0-9 characters are allowed only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
(?<=\s|^)@([\w@]+)
```

There is a positive lookbehind assertion to make sure the tag is preceded by whitespace, or the start of the string. After that it's just a case of consuming the `@` character and putting the username inside a capturing group.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iL3tM7/1)

Comment: Tips: `(?<=\s|^)` is the same than `(?<!\S)`.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `/(?:\s@{1,3})([a-zA-Z@.]+)/i`

---

**Explain**

@ Character. Matches a "@" character (char code 64).
{1,3} Quantifier. Match between 1 and 3 of the preceding token.

\w Word. Matches any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).
+ Plus. Match 1 or more of the preceding token.

Here is regexr: http://regexr.com/3djhq

Comment: That incorrectly matches the example `a@john`, and matches twice instead of once on the example `@Sam@something`.

Comment: @duskwuff: thanks for pointing out.
Now this will ignore space and allow @ in username.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is almost correct. 
Firstly, you want to say that your regex should match also the begining of the string. You can achieve that with caret symbol (^):

```
^@([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

Secondly, you want to be able to put the @ sign inside. Now it's easy - just add that symbol inside the brackets.

```
^@([A-Za-z0-9@]+)
```

Comment: The `^` would make the regex **only** match usernames appearing at the beginning of a string, which I don't think is desired.

Comment: Haha, I too didn't read the question very clearly and already provided this same answer.  @duskwuff is correct.

Comment: Well, the author has said that _It should only match a string that starts with the @ symbol_